# Monitor outgoing request body using nsihttpchannel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I understand that nsIHttpChannel can be used to monitor and manipulate HTTP request/response headers.
However, I am unable to find a way to read the request body (POSTed data). Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try querying the channel to an [nsIUploadChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIUploadChannel) and accessing its `uploadStream`.